# position fixed bar does scroll

Tags: jquery, html, css

I got part of it working. But for some reason it won't stay at the top.

CSS Navbox:

```
#navbox {
        float: left;                
        width: 150px;
        border: 1px solid blue;
        border: thin solid #CCC;
        background-color: #FFF;
        border-radius: 4px;
        padding: 5px; 
        position: fixed;
        top: 92px;  
        z-index: 1000;
    }
```

HTML Code:

```
<div id="navbox">
    <div class="navigation">
      <a href="#aeast">AFC East</a> <br />
      <a href="#anorth">AFC North</a> <br />
      <a href="#asouth">AFC South</a> <br />
      <a href="#awest">AFC West</a> <br />
    </div>
</div>
```

When It's not scrolled.
[image]
When I scroll
[image]
it's something to do with the `top` i guess.

It's in a container with the middle part.

container is:

```
#container {
    width: 870px;
    margin-top: 12px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;                                         
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The only option here is to use JavaScript to determine scroll position prior to making the item `position: fixed;`. I recommend [ScrollToFixed](https://github.com/bigspotteddog/ScrollToFixed) as it has support for boundaries and margins.

**Update:**

You can use `position: sticky;` (and with browser prefixes) [[reference](https://github.com/bigspotteddog/ScrollToFixed/issues/100#issuecomment-37659322)] in order to do this in more creative ways, and especially to fix it for iOS.

Answer (score 0):

`position:fixed` is relative to the **browser window**, whereas `position:absolute;` is relative to the **document**, or closest parent with `position:relative`.

So in your case by using `position:fixed`, the div will always be **92px below the top of the browser window** (`top:92px`).  If you want it to scroll up (be the same distance from the top of the page), use `position:absolute`.

---

**fiddles**

1. `position:fixed` - http://jsfiddle.net/yB45v/
2. `position:absolute` - http://jsfiddle.net/43SZW/

Answer (score 0):

you can give a `position:fixed` or `position:absolute` value to move the div any specific location on the page.

while using `position:absolute' the parent div position should be relative.

so the conclusion is you can set it by these 2 methods

```
.element{ position:fixed; top:2%; right:2%; }
.element{ position:absolute; top:50px; right:50px; } /*parent div should be in relative position.
```